# How could I update certain value when my array is being added a new element

Tags: javascript

I have an array of products along with production years, there is an item to keep track of the longest production year as well

When I add a new product, how could I sync with the latest longest production year?

Below are my code.

```
const bucket = {
  longestYear: 2060,
  Category_A: [
    { productName: "toothpaste", productionYear: 2030 },
    { productName: "shampo", productionYear: 2040 },
  ],
  Category_B: [
    { productName: "Macbook", productionYear: 2025 },
    { productName: "Micosoft_computer", productionYear: 2060 },
  ],
};
```

I have a variable to keep track of the longest production years among all products. And my add new elements function.

```
const addProduct = (bucket,category,newProduct) => {

bucket[category].push(newProduct)
}

 addProduct(bucket,'Category_B',{ productName: "ASUS", productionYear: 2070 })
 console.log(bucket);
```

---

In addition to this, how could I also deal with the cases of delete element, while sync with longest year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const bucket = {
  longestYear: 2060,
  Category_A: [
    { productName: "toothpaste", productionYear: 2030 },
    { productName: "shampo", productionYear: 2040 },
  ],
  Category_B: [
    { productName: "Macbook", productionYear: 2025 },
    { productName: "Micosoft_computer", productionYear: 2060 },
  ],
};

const addProduct = (bucket,category,newProduct) => {
bucket.longestYear = Math.max(bucket.longestYear, newProduct.productionYear)
bucket[category].push(newProduct)
}

 addProduct(bucket,'Category_B',{ productName: "ASUS", productionYear: 2070 })
 console.log(bucket);
```

Comment: if i need to delete one element and want to keep track of the longest year, can I also do it in this clean version?

Comment: if element that you're deleting has lower productYear than longesYear - you can delete without changing anything, but if it's equal, then you need to go through all elements to find next longest

Comment: May I see an example of doing this like how you handle with different cases in deletinh?

Comment: it'll look somewhat like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75187442/17431816

Answer (score 1):

```js
const bucket = {
  longestYear: 2060,
  Category_A: [
    { productName: "toothpaste", productionYear: 2030 },
    { productName: "shampo", productionYear: 2040 },
  ],
  Category_B: [
    { productName: "Macbook", productionYear: 2025 },
    { productName: "Micosoft_computer", productionYear: 2060 },
  ],
}

function addProduct(bucket, cat, item) {
  (bucket[cat]??=[]).push(item)
  bucket.longestYear = Object.values(bucket)
    .filter(Array.isArray)
    .flatMap(a=>a.map(i=>i.productionYear)).sort().pop()
}

addProduct(bucket, 'Category_B', { productName: "ASUS", productionYear: 2070 })

console.log(bucket);
```

Comment: could you explain a bit this part :bucket.longestYear = Object.values(bucket)
    .filter(Array.isArray)
    .flatMap(a=>a.map(i=>i.productionYear)).sort().pop()

Comment: @AeLeung it needs to find all properties of bucket that are arrays, then for each array extract all production years. Then, flatMap converts the array of production year arrays to just a single array containing a list of all years. Finally, we sort them, and the largest number will appear last. Then, pop() returns that largest number

Comment: I'd suggest to change bucket structure to an array of objects `{ productName: "Macbook", productionYear: 2025, category: "A" }` would be easier to maintain I think. or object `{longestYear: 2060, products: [
  { productName: "Macbook", productionYear: 2025, category: "A" }
]`

Comment: thanks @AndrewParks , a bit complicated, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you push a new object, you compare the `productionYear` with what you already have in `longestYear`
I added this

```
if(newProduct.productionYear > bucket.longestYear){
   bucket.longestYear=newProduct.productionYear;
}
```

so it looks like this

```js
const bucket = {
  longestYear: 2060,
  Category_A: [
    { productName: "toothpaste", productionYear: 2030 },
    { productName: "shampo", productionYear: 2040 },
  ],
  Category_B: [
    { productName: "Macbook", productionYear: 2025 },
    { productName: "Micosoft_computer", productionYear: 2060 },
  ],
};

const addProduct = (bucket,category,newProduct) => {
    if(newProduct.productionYear > bucket.longestYear){
       bucket.longestYear=newProduct.productionYear;
    }
    bucket[category].push(newProduct)
}

 addProduct(bucket,'Category_B',{ productName: "ASUS", productionYear: 2070 })
 console.log(bucket);
```